# 6502 and little-endian conversion

Tags: emulation, 6502

For fun I'm implementing an NES emulator.  I'm currently reading through documentation for the 6502 CPU and I'm a little confused.

I've seen documentation stating because the 6502 is little-endian so when using absolute addressing mode you need to swap the bytes.  I'm writing this on an x86 machine which is also little-endian, so I don't understand why I couldn't simply cast to a uint16_t*, dereference that, and let the compiler work out the details.

I've written some simple tests in google test and they seem to agree with me.

```
// implementation of READ16
#define READ16(addr) (*(uint16_t*)addr)

TEST(MemMacro, READ16) {
  uint8_t arr[] = {0xFF,0xCC};
  uint8_t *mem = (&arr[0]);

  EXPECT_EQ(0xCCFF, READ16(mem));
}
```

This passes, so it appears my supposition is correct, but I thought I'd ask someone with more experience than I.

Is this correct for pulling out the operand in 6502 absolute addressing mode?  Am I possibly missing something?

Comment: Can you point us to that documentation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will work for simple cases on little-endian systems, but tying your implementation to those feels unnecessary when the corresponding portable implementation is simple. Sticking to the macro, you could do this instead:

```
#define READ16(addr) (addr[0] + (addr[1] << 8))
```

(Just to be pedantic, you should also make sure that `addr[1]` can't be out-of-bounds, and would need to add some more parentheses if `addr` could be a complex expression.)

However, as you keep developing your emulator, you will find that it's most natural to use a pair of general-purpose `read_mem()` and `write_mem()` functions that operate on single bytes. Remember that the address space is split up into multiple regions (RAM, ROM, and memory-mapped registers from the PPU and APU), so having e.g. a single array that you index into won't work well. The fact that memory regions can be remapped by mappers also complicates things. (You won't have to worry about that for simple games though -- I recommend starting with Donkey Kong.)

What you need to do is to figure out what region or memory-mapped register the address belongs to inside your `read_mem()` and `write_mem()` functions (this is called *address decoding*), and do the right thing for the address.

Returning to the original question, the fact that you'll end up using `read_mem()` to read the individual bytes of the address anyway means that the `uint16_t` casting trickery is even less likely to be useful. This is the simplest and most robust approach w.r.t. handling corner cases, and what every emulator I've seen does in practice (Nestopia, Nintendulator, and FCEUX).

In case you've missed it, the *#nesdev* channel on EFNet is very active and a good resource by the way. I assume you're already familiar with the NESDev wiki. :)

I've also been working on an emulator which can be found [here](https://github.com/ulfalizer/nesalizer).

Comment: I've since moved on to using read8/read16 methods for exactly the reasons you mentioned.  I originally just jumped into writing a 6502 core with flat memory for simplicity, and I've since realized that's a bad approach.  I don't understand why you wouldn't be able to simply cast though, if an implementation is asking you to read16 at the last byte of a bounds, wouldn't that represent a bug in the code itself and not the emulator?  What does the CPU do in that case, wrap around?  This is actually something I've been wondering about

Comment: and thank you for taking the time to post such a complete response.

Comment: No problem! Yup, you usually get wraparound. Masking the address is a simple way to implement it, i.e. `(addr + 1) & 0xFFFF` for 16-bit wraparound and `(addr + 1) & 0xFF` for 8-bit wraparound. One place where you need to be careful is with the indexed indirect and indirect indexed addressing modes, which should wrap around *within the zero page*. The `nestest` and `instr_test` test ROMs at http://wiki.nesdev.com/w/index.php/Emulator_tests include wrapping tests.

Comment: You might even run into wraparound issues with the PC if you execute instructions at the top of the address space. That'd be very weird though, since the interrupt vector lives there. You'd wrap around to the zero page. :)

Comment: (The above is assuming `addr` is an index variable and not a C pointer of course.)

Comment: Ok, that helps a lot.  Had I understood that originally I would have saved myself some time :)

Comment: Do you have any resources for picking up 6502 assembler?  I've been trying to use dasm and I've been having a heck of a time attempting to sift through all of the information online.  A lot of it doesn't seem to be relevant, or is outdated, and so forth.  A good book I could purchase and sit down to read would be perfect (multiple books would be good too)

Comment: To be perfectly honest I haven't done much NES development besides implementing the emulator. http://nintendoage.com/pub/faq/NA/nerdy_nights_out.html is a tutorial I see mentioned a lot. I just implemented each instruction as spec'd, picking things up and correcting misunderstandings as I went. http://wiki.nesdev.com/w/index.php/CPU has good CPU-related resources.

Comment: Thanks for those links, I'll look over them.  My issue is that I don't know if the opcodes are implemented correctly so I want to test them, but that implies being able to produce 6502 binaries.  I'm actually finding that to be more difficult than understanding and implementing the opcodes...

Comment: What I did when starting out was to jump to the entry point of a ROM (you get it from the reset vector) and trace the instructions as they were executed to see that they did the right thing. (You'll eventually get stuck in a loop that's waiting for VBlank. At that point you'll have to add some PPU functionality.) Once you have basic functionality, you can start running test ROMs. There are lots of great test ROMs for NES emulators.