# 6502 Indirect acces mode

Tags: 6502

My question is about the 6502 Assembly language. I'm trying to learn it using this website https://skilldrick.github.io/easy6502/.

On the topic of addressing modes. I don't understand the indirect addressing mode. See the source code example below.

```
LDA #$01
STA $f0
LDA #$cc
STA $f1
JMP ($00f0) ;dereferences to $cc01
```

Why is the `JMP ($00f0)` dereferenced to `$cc01` instead of `$01cc`.

My memory looks like this

`00f0: 01 cc 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 84`

Here you see `00f0` starts with `01` and then followed by `cc` so it looks more logical to me that the jump instruction would dereference to `$01cc`, but why is this somehow reversed?

Comment: [The 6502 is little-endian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874246/6502-and-little-endian-conversion).

Comment: There are 01 kinds of people. Those who understand endianness ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

6502 is little endian. That means for 16 bit values, which take two bytes, the lowest byte is stored at the lowest address. After the two `STA`s, you have:

```
00f0: 01 
00f1: cc
```

The `JMP` instruction loads the byte at `f0` into the low byte of the destination address and the byte at `f1` into the high byte of the destination address meaning you jump to `cc01`.

Answer (score 4):

An additional answer on "*why* is this somehow reversed?": little endian obeys the direction in which carry runs, so is cheaper to implement. You have enough information to start doing arithmetic before you have all the information.

This is the cycle breakdown of 6502 when dealing with an `$aabb, X` instruction:

1. fetch instruction
2. fetch low byte of operand address
3. add low byte of operand address to X register, fetch high byte of operand address
4. read from address with high byte $aa and low byte $bb + X, if there was carry then work out $aa+1 for use in a moment...
5. if there was carry then read from proper address

So if that's `LDA` then the cost is four cycles if you don't cross a page boundary, five if you do. Now imagine addresses were stored in big endian format. Then:

1. fetch instruction
2. fetch high byte of operand address
3. fetch low byte of operand address
4. add X to low byte of operand address
5. read from address with high byte $aa and low byte $bb + X, if there was carry then work out $aa+1 for use in a moment...
6. if there was carry then read from proper address

So you've increased cost by a cycle. You can't start until you have the low byte, and you're getting the low byte a cycle later.

So if you do not arrange things so that the lowest byte is fetched first then you are losing time.